# Select most recent InstanceID base on max end date

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull the memberinstance from a table based on the max DateEnd. If it is Null I want to pull that as it would be still ongoing. I am using sql server.

 
select memberinstanceid 
from table 
group by memberid 
having MAX(ISNULL(date_end, '2099-12-31'))

This query above doesnt work for me. I have tried different ones and have gotten it to return the separate instances, but not just the one with the max date.

Below is what my table looks like.

MemberID         MemberInstanceID        DateStart        DateEnd 
       2                      abc12                 2013-01-01   2013-12-31 
        4                      abc21                  2010-01-01     2013-12-31 
        2                      abc10                  2015-01-01        NULL 
       4                      abc19                 2014-01-01    2014-10-31

I would expect my results to look like this

MemberInstanceID 
     abc10 
     abc19

I have been trying to figure out how to do this but have not had much luck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this really related to the **Microsoft SQL Server**? If not, please remove the *sql-server* tag.

Generally, add some more background, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like the following:

```
select MemberID, MemberInstanceID
from table t
where (
    -- DateEnd is null...
    DateEnd is null
    or (
        -- ...or pick the latest DateEnd for this member...
        DateEnd = (
            select max(DateEnd)
            from table
            where MemberID = t.MemberID
        )
        -- ... and check there's not a NULL entry for DateEnd for this member
        and not exists (
            select 1
            from table
            where MemberID = t.MemberID
            and DateEnd is null
        )
    )
)
```

The problem with this approach would be if there are multiple rows that match for each member, i.e. multiple NULL rows with the same MemberID, or multiple rows with the same DateEnd for the same MemberID.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 memberinstanceid 
from table 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [DateEnd] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, 
     [DateEnd] DESC
```

The ORDER BY is essentially creating a "column" to sort the NULL values to the top, then doing a secondary sort on the dates that are not null.

Comment: Thanks. this works but only returns one result. Im looking for it to return the results by member.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start but you don't need to perform any explicit grouping. What you want is the row where the EndDate is null or is the largest value (latest date) of all the records with the same MemberID. You also realized that the Max couldn't return the latest non-null date because the null, if one exists, must be the latest date.

```
select  m.*
from    Members m
where   m.DateEnd   is null
    or  m.DateEnd   =(
        select  Max( IsNull( DateEnd, '9999-12-31' ))
        from    Members
        where   MemberID    = m.MemberID );
```